# Generate random alphanumeric string into password field

Tags: asp.net, textbox, auto-generate, alphanumeric, jpasswordfield

I want to  generate a random alphanumeric string into password field when click a button.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
```

code behind the button

```
var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
var stringChars = new char[8];
var random = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < stringChars.Length; i++)
            {
                stringChars[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
            }

var finalString = new String(stringChars);

txtPassword.Text = finalString.ToString();
```

**this execute without any error.. but does not appear any text in textbox. 
When I use**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

This works properly..

I have no any idea why my code is not working..

Please help me to  solve this problem...

Comment: TextMode="Password", I suppose you can't assign it like this.
Have you tried using with normal mode?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add text to password mode textfield then you need to write.

```
txtPassword.Attributes.Add("value", finalString.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to add using attributes

```
txtPassword.Attributes.Add("value", finalString.ToString());
```

please refer below link for more information on this.

http://www.tyronedavisjr.com/2008/05/23/aspnet-and-password-textbox-with-initial-value/