# Auto generation of code

Tags: asp.net, alphanumeric

I want to auto generate an alphanumeric code in ASP.net using C#. I want that first 3 words must be characters and then 7 must be integers.

Comment: Sounds like a great project! Let us know when you have a question. Btw, pls do not shout (allcaps).

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: Related: [generate-random-alphanumeric-string-into-password-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874086/generate-random-alphanumeric-string-into-password-field?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Create one table in SQL.With the Columns of "ID" and "AutoCode"...Create on Stored Procedure by getting the maximum value of the ID and add one to it..and insert into the table..You can put one select statement and that Code...on Each Page load you can get autogenerated AutoCode..

If you cannt reach me.Mail me..(Shahul.shagy@gmail.com)